# Shiny splitLayout not wrapping HTML text

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using `splitLayout` in a Shiny R app to create a two-panel structure that has a plot on the left (a `googleVis` `gVisGeoChart` object) and HTML on the right.

This is a mockup of the problematic code:

```
splitLayout(

    htmlOutput("mychart"), #This winds up rendering properly to the left side of the window

    div(
        h1("A descriptive heading"),
        p("Here's some text that takes more than one line on the screen. I want it to wrap, but it just keeps going to the right out of view in its container.")      
    ) #This text will not wrap to the right side of the splitLayout frame
)
```

The text inside the p() command will not wrap to the visible (1/2) of the page created by splitLayout. Instead, it keeps going to the (invisible) right, requiring the user to scroll to see it all. This is not the desired behavior (quite frankly, I have a hard time imagining a situation where it is).

How to ensure that the text wraps properly to the splitLayout area?

Comment: Actually, the display in the code block of my question is a good example of the error. Shiny renders my HTML in the right 1/2 of the page like that, rather than wrapping the text into the frame.

Answer (score 14):

Super old, but I've been stuck on this issue for a while and the previous answer did not work. Finally figured it out thanks to some html inspection. You need to add a style element to splitLayout, namely: 'white-space: normal', (it is set to 'white-space: nowrap' by default for splitLayout). See below for it used in context with the original question.

```
splitLayout(

htmlOutput("mychart"), #This winds up rendering properly to the left side of the window

div(
    h1("A descriptive heading"),
    p("Here's some text that takes more than one line on the screen. I want it to wrap, but it just keeps going to the right out of view in its container.")      
),
cellArgs = list(style='white-space: normal;')
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out!

Comment: This worked for me too - thanks a lot! I had been stressing over this for like 45 min.

Answer (score 3):

Add `style = "word-wrap: break-word;"`:

```
p("Here's some text that takes more than one line on the screen. I want it to wrap, but it just keeps going to the right out of view in its container.",
   style = "word-wrap: break-word;")
```